# Add default content to wp_editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to know how I can add a couple of paragraphs when viewing wp_editor. I'm using a PHP snippet plugin to show wp_editor on the front end & need to add some instruction text when the editor loads.

Code:

```
wp_editor( $distribution, 'distribution', array( 'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, ul, pH, pH_min', "media_buttons" => false, "textarea_rows" => 15, "tabindex" => 4 ) );
```

Can anyone help me?

Cheers

Comment: Are you using the Divi editor or some other custom editor or just the default WP editor?

Comment: I'm using the default editor with the Tiny MCE plugin enabled. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function

```
add_filter('default_content', 'my_editor_content');
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
    $content = &quot;If you enjoyed this post, make sure to subscribe to my rss feed.&lt;br&gt;This goes on the second line&quot;;
    return $content;
}
```

or you can use this

```
if($content == ""){
$content = "default content";
}
wp_editor( string $content, string $editor_id);
```

Comment: @Anna Wellington is the issue fixed or not